# Spread elements evenly using Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm starting with Flexbox and I'm trying to center a row with three columns to the center of the document. I've tried the following code (Written in Sass) but as you can see in the screenshot the three elements are not perfectly centered (they don't have the same space between them):

HTML for the header:

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="active">ELE 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ELEMENT 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ELEMENT 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

SCSS for the header:

```
header {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: $dark-grey;
}

nav {
  height: inherit;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  & ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    & li {
      flex: 1 0 auto;
      & a, a:visited {
        color: $white-alpha;
      }
      & a.active {
        color: $white;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

I've recreated the problem in this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KWaNpY), as you can see the real example. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what is the desired effect.

Comment: is this what you're going for? http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/QpdGdP

Comment: Hi @AdamWolski , the desired effect is to have the ELEMENT 2 centered with the HEADER (which is aligned to the center of the document).

Comment: Don't set the basis `auto` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dvNOzV

Comment: @EliasGarcia flexbox is a flexible. ) in this case, the column width depends on the length of the text. more text is wider than column. set each column equal size will be as you want. for exam remove `auto` for `li` -  `flex: 1 0;`

Comment: @EliasGarcia change `flex: 1 0;` to  `width: 100%;`

Comment: *"the desired effect is to have the ELEMENT 2 centered with the HEADER"* `flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 0;` http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/QpdGdP

Comment: Hi @AndreyFedorov , thanks for the explanation, I thought it was just the opposite. Also Adam Wolski and Michael Coker answers works perfectly, thanks!